# How to render a JSON file with the Phoenix framework?

Tags: json, elixir, phoenix-framework

Instead of fetching data from a database, I want to use as data a manually written JSON file. Suppose my data is this:

```
[
    { "id": 1, "name": "Alice", "email": "alice@example.com" },
    { "id": 2, "name": "Bob", "email": "bob@example" },
    { "id": 3, "name": "Charles", "email": "charles@example.com"}
]
```

and it's written in a file called `MOCK_DATA.json`. What should I do to render this file when I access the `localhost:port/api/v1/users` url? How about the `localhost:port/api/v1/users/1` url to show `{ "id": 1, "name": "Alice", "email": "alice@example.com" }`?

Comment: So you just want to mock the response to get started quickly, and replace it with a "real" implementation later on? This does not have to be production ready I guess?

Comment: @PatrickOscity yes, exactly.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Here is a basic working example...

Step 1: Create the phoenix app

eg, exjson for ExampleJson or whatever name your like

```
mix phoenix.new exjson --no-ecto --no-brunch --no-html
```

Step 2: Set up the router

Add this scope to the web/router.ex file

```
  scope "/api/v1", Exjson do
    pipe_through :api
    resources "/users", UserController
  end
```

Step 3: Put the mock data somewhere accessible to the app

```
priv/data/MOCK_DATA.json
```

Step 4: Set up the UsersController

Think of the Users Controller as having a number of actions (functions)
where the [conn struct](https://hexdocs.pm/plug/Plug.Conn.html) is fed into from your phoenix endpoint along with any
parameters

```
defmodule Exjson.UserController do
  use Exjson.Web, :controller

  # GET http://localhost:4000/api/v1/users/
  def index(conn, _params) do
    users = File.read!(file) |> Poison.decode!()
    render conn, users: users
  end

  # GET http://localhost:4000/api/v1/users/1
  def show(conn, params) do
    users = File.read!(file) |> Poison.decode!()
    render conn, user: users |> Enum.find(&(&1["id"] === String.to_integer(params["id"])))
  end

  defp file() do
    Path.join(:code.priv_dir(:exjson), "data/MOCK_DATA.json")
  end

end
```

Step 5: Set up the UsersView

You can also think of the Users View as having functions that will render the data received from the Controller in the appropriate way. In this case, you are using json data so [phoenix](https://hexdocs.pm/phoenix/Phoenix.View.html#content) has some built in functions to help with that.

```
defmodule Exjson.UserView do
  use Exjson.Web, :view

  def render("index.json", %{users: users}) do
    render_many(users, __MODULE__, "user.json")
  end

  def render("show.json", %{user: user}) do
    render_one(user, __MODULE__, "user.json")
  end

  def render("user.json", %{user: user}) do
    %{
      id: user["id"],
      name: user["name"],
      email: user["email"]
    }
  end

end
```

Comment: If you are only sending json in your api then terms of rendering the data on the browser, often nowadays, developers are using so called 'Single Page Apps' frameworks to create the user interface (browser component). Eg [Aurelia](http://aurelia.io/), [Angular2](https://angular.io/) but that is just to name a few, there are many....

Comment: What is the `:code.priv_dir(:exjson)` parameter in the `Path.join` function? I searched the phoenix source code but my search came up empty.

Comment: It's a function from an [erlang library](http://erlang.org/doc/man/code.html#priv_dir-1).. it just gets your priv folder. Files in this folder are available to the application.

Comment: Noting if this helps someone else, I had to change the last render function to use `%{users: user}` (users vs user), but I'm still new to this and I might not be understanding something.

Answer (score 12):

To give you some real code to get started, this is the simplest thing I can think of:

```
defmodule MyApp.UserController do
  @mock_data (
    Application.app_dir(:my_app, "priv/mock_data/users.json")
    |> File.read!
    |> Poison.decode!
  )

  def index(conn, _params) do
    conn
    |> put_status(:ok)
    |> json(@mock_data)
  end
end
```

Then just save your fake data in `priv/mock_data/users.json` inside your project. There might be typos in there, but you get the basic idea...

Answer (score 3):

Since you're just echoing the JSON back for the `/users` endpoint, in that case you don't need the `Poison.decode/1` call which does unnecessary decoding/encoding of the JSON.

So, adapting Patrick's code:

```
defmodule MyApp.UserController do
  @mock_data_string (
    Application.app_dir(:my_app, "priv/mock_data/users.json")
    |> File.read!
  )

  def index(conn, _params) do
    conn
    |> put_resp_content_type("application/json")
    |> send_resp(200, @mock_data_string)
  end
end
```

However, for the `/users/1` endpoint, it is best to extract values by using `Poison.decode/1`, as @stephen_m's answer illustrates.

Comment: That's nice! I'm just in need of something similar (just forwarding JSON data from another server via Phoenix). I'll give it a try!

Answer (score 1):

If the file is static (does not change for the course of the service running) then you can read it when the app compiles in your controller. Look into module parameters (the ones you define in your module, outside of functions). This way i'll be parsed once.

If this file is dynamic then you may need to read it every time the API is called and parse it. Not really advised since reading a file from disk IO will slow it down.

In any case the result of the file, parsed to a Map can then be passed in into the view and rendered, no difference from the database.

Edit: another suggestion is to reformat your JSON (if possible) and have `id` as a key and the rest of the data as a value. This way lookups by `id` will be very fast, just like a primary key index in the database.

Comment: I'm a beginner, both in Phoenix and in Elixir, so I didn't understood your answer. Could you give me some code examples? Also, thanks for your performance tips, but at this point I don't even know how to render the data on the browser, so I would appreciate specific instructions on that area.